# Add content of SELECT to LIST

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android

I've just started learning Xamarin and i would like to add content of SELECT query to `List<SearchModel>`. How can i do it? I've created Object model, according to Sqlite.

```
 List<SearchModel> searchModelsList = new List<SearchModel>();

try
        {
            using (sQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(path))
            {
                try
                {
                   
                 sQLiteConnection.Execute("SELECT * FROM CONTENT_TABLE);

                    }
                catch (Exception ex) { 

                }


            }

        }
        catch (Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("exex", ex.Message);

        }


 class SearchModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PERSON { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Anything update? please give feedback to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've just started learning Xamarin and i would like to add content of SELECT query to List. How can i do it? I've created Object model, according to Sqlite.

If you want to query data from sqlite database, you can take a look the following code:

```
 <StackLayout>

        <Button
            x:Name="createdb"
            Clicked="createdb_Clicked"
            Text="create table in sqlite" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btnadd"
            Clicked="btnadd_Clicked"
            Text="add data to sqlite" />

        <Button
            x:Name="btnfetdata"
            Clicked="btnfetdata_Clicked"
            Text="get data from sqlite" />

    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public SQLiteConnection conn;
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       conn= GetSQLiteConnection();
    }
    public SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection()
    {
        var fileName = "SearchModel.db";
        var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);

        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        return connection;
    }

    private void btnadd_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var data = conn.Table<SearchModel>();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            SearchModel model = new SearchModel();
            model.PERSON = "person "+ i;
            model.NAME = "cherry "+ i;
            conn.Insert(model);
        }
    }
    private List<SearchModel> searchModelsList;
    private void btnfetdata_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchModelsList = conn.Table<SearchModel>().ToList();

        var searchlist = conn.Query<SearchModel>("SELECT * FROM SearchModel WHERE PERSON = ?", "person 1");
    }

    private void createdb_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.CreateTable<SearchModel>();
    }
}

public class SearchModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PERSON { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

About querying data, you can use

```
var searchlist = conn.Query<SearchModel>("SELECT * FROM SearchModel WHERE PERSON = ?", "person 1");
```

But you can also get the entire SearchModel table, then query data from List

```
searchModelsList = conn.Table<SearchModel>().ToList();

        var list = searchModelsList.Where(p => p.PERSON == "person 1");
```

Comment: Please refrain from begging for votes on this platform. If you have a particular reason to suspect that the poster does not know how to use the voting system, then by all means explain it in the comments, but go easy on it. Please don't put this commentary in your posts, it is just clutter.